# Multi Column equality Restrictions in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE routes (
start text,
end text,
validFrom timestamp,
validTo timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (start, end, validFrom, validTo)
);
```

How would one write a cql query to find all routes that go from point A to point B and are valid between date x and date y.  Essentially the equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * from routes where start = 'A' and end = 'B' and validFrom <= x and validTo >= y.
```

I've been reading through the [Cassandra Docs](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) and my impression is that such a query is not possible with the given table.  If this is the case then how might one model the data in order to enable such a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * from routes where start = 'A' and end = 'B' and validFrom <= x and validTo >= y
```

Due to the way in which Cassandra stores its data on-disk, it can't pull a consecutive range of rows for a query like that.  So what you need to do is adjust your model slightly.

```
CREATE TABLE routes (
  start text,
  end text,
  valid timestamp,
  toFrom text,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (start, end, valid, toFrom)
);
```

By consolidating the to/from `valid` times into a single column, you are now allowed to execute a range query on it, checking for a beginning and an end.  Each row will need to be stored twice.  Once with the "Valid To" time and once with the "Valid From" time.  The `toFrom` column helps differentiate this.

Now I can run this query:

```
> SELECT * FROM routes 
    WHERE start='A' AND end='B' 
    AND valid>='2016-02-01'AND valid<='2016-02-20';

 start | end | valid                    | tofrom | name
-------+-----+--------------------------+--------+---------
     A |   B | 2016-02-01 06:00:00+0000 |      F | combo 1
     A |   B | 2016-02-14 06:00:00+0000 |      T | combo 1
     A |   B | 2016-02-15 06:00:00+0000 |      F | combo 2

(3 rows)
```

Just a thought, but it might make sense to use a composite partition key (like `PRIMARY KEY ((start, end), valid, toFrom)`) for better data distribution.  Although that really depends on your query patterns....so that won't work if you'd ever need to query for all rows that start with "A" (for example).

**Edit 20160221**

> I accepted your answer but now I thought about it some more I don't think this will work. E.g. I think the query: SELECT * FROM routes WHERE start='A' AND end='B' AND valid>='2016-02-01' AND valid<='2016-02-13'; will yield no results even though the "Combo 1" route should be valid.

Actually, that *does* work:

```
> SELECT * FROM routes 
    WHERE start='A' AND end='B' 
    AND valid>='2016-02-01'AND valid<='2016-02-13';

 start | end | valid                    | tofrom | name
-------+-----+--------------------------+--------+---------
     A |   B | 2016-02-01 06:00:00+0000 |      F | combo 1

(1 rows)
```

That being said, I understand what you're getting at.  If you should select a time period that happens between the valid to/from (not inclusive), it will yield zero rows...like this:

```
    > SELECT * FROM routes 
    WHERE start='A' AND end='B' 
    AND valid>='2016-02-02'AND valid<='2016-02-13';

 start | end | valid                    | tofrom | name
-------+-----+--------------------------+--------+---------

(0 rows)
```

That's a valid concern.  Two points about that:

1. In terms of your question which asked for the **"equivalent to the following SQL statement"**, you would still have this same problem in a relational database (tried it on my MariaDB test instance).  Actually, it'd be worse, as a query for `valid>='2016-02-01'AND valid<='2016-02-13'` returns one row in Cassandra, but `validFrom>='2016-02-01' AND validTo<='2016-02-13'` returns nothing in MariaDB.
2. This really becomes a business logic problem, inconsequential of your datastore.  To avoid this issue, you should take a look at your business logic/requirements, and determine the maximum time between `valid` to/from.  You can then adjust your query so that it always exceeds that time.  Example: if routes are only valid for a maximum of two or three weeks, then querying for one month at a time should suffice.

Comment: ah- I accepted your answer but now I thought about it some more I don't think this will work.  E.g. I think the query: 
`SELECT * FROM routes WHERE start='A' AND end='B'  AND valid>='2016-02-01' AND valid<='2016-02-13';`
will yield no results even though the "Combo 1" route should be valid.

Comment: apologies- I made a typo in my original sql statement. It should have been 
**validFrom <= x and validTo <= y**.  I 've just re-accepted your answer as it do of course answer my original question.